# Incorrect answer when matching rows on two criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This should be so simple, yet is so painful.

I merely want to find the most recent scores for each ID. My data looks like this:

```
ID       DATE   SCORE1  SCORE2
747     1/4/12     1      -6
747     1/28/11    1      -6
747     4/21/10    0       1
747     2/6/13     1      -6
747     3/4/09     1      -6
747     3/19/08    1      -6
747     11/8/06    1      -6
2442    5/3/12     1      -6
2442    1/13/15    1      -6
2442    5/4/11     1      -6
2442    6/2/10     1      -6
2442    5/8/09     1      -6
```

The result should look like this:

```
ID       DATE   SCORE1  SCORE2
747     2/6/13     1      -6
2442    1/13/15    1      -6
```

I would think this is one of the most common operations imaginable in excel.

I googled around and found out that a pivot table isn't the right solution for multiple criteria. I eventually found a nice tutorial [here](http://exceltactics.com/vlookup-multiple-criteria-using-index-match/).

The formula `=INDEX(A2:D431,MATCH(1,(A:A=A2)*(B:B=MAX(B2)),0),1)` makes sense to me. But for some reason I keep getting the incorrect date. I don't understand what is wrong with this simple formula. My data is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2k8rnti87zp5ohz/SO.xlsx?dl=0).

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your two ID's to be found are in G2 and G3, please try in H2 and copied down:

```
=MAX(IF(A:A=G2,B:B))
```

entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter

and then look up the matching Scores to suit (say with VLOOKUP).